# Problem using rigid-body physics with a Trebuchet

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

Blender newbie here. I was trying to follow the tutorial: "[Blender 2.8 Physics Tutorial - Make a Working Trebuchet!](https://youtu.be/CApB_DyiU-o)". And I am struggling with the physics part. I keep getting a result that looks like [this](https://gyazo.com/dac4470965bc1f3c328cded20b9a6950), despite following the steps. Any help would be appreciated. Link to the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y3i6sof11tC7oosoAFgx-dO1VmGWs3Gj/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Nevermind, my problem was that I duplicated the axle, so I assigned the wrong items for a rigid body constraint.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)